# Listing Objects with multiple prefixes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My structure on AWS S3 is something like so:

```
photos
  -->  PA
  -->  NJ
  -->  NY
  --> etc...
```

As you can see it is a flat folder structure which lists each state.

My question is I would like to list all the objects in each folder based on some set of parameters.  So in some cases I may want to load all objects in the PA and NY folder.  In some other cases I may want to load all objects in the PA NJ folder.

I am aware that the prefix parameter in the listObjectsV2 function allows you to specify only one path.  Is there a way to specify multiple paths(or prefixes) without making multiple separate calls?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make multiple calls. You might be able to use a filter property in a single query, but even if you could, that would force S3 to iterate over every file in `/photos/` to compare against your filter, which would be both slow and resource intensive.